# How do I know what doc type header to use for my pages?

Tags: html

I do some coding in HTML, and was wondering what doc type header to use. How do I know if I am coding in HTML 4.0.1 Strict or HTML 4.0.1 Transitional? (or any other type)

Comment: @Daniel A. White — Err, yes there is: [strict](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) and [transitional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/loosedtd.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should choose DOCTYPE depending on the HTML tags that you use and your HTML writing style. Let me clarify that.

HTML 4.0.1 Strict - Basically allows zero style tags. For styling such pages you should only use CSS. Some tags that are not allowed in Strict: `<center> <font> <u>` etc. Also note that Strict requires closing tags for everything. You must use this:

```
<img .... /> <br /> instead of this: <img ... ><br>
```

Also in Strict all tags have to be nested correctly. Therefore, this style is cleaner and better formated. This makes it more reliable in the long run.

HTML 4.0.1 Transitional - Allows all those style tags and some other deprecated HTML tags. Also it does not require to use closing tags everywhere. In my personal opinion Transitional is really the lazy coders choice and should only be used in very specific situations.

*You can read more about the differences between DOTCYPE's here:*

[Converting XHTML transitional to HTML 4.01 strict](http://www.accessifyforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=9587)

[What is and what isn't XHTML](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTML_to_XHTML)

*Also read more about DOCTYPE's from W3Schools here:*

[HTML !DOCTYPE Declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

[HTML HTML 4.01 / XHTML 1.0 Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I would say forget about HTML4 and, if you can, start now to use the HTML5 doctype

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/

Answer (score 0):

It is what practice you are doing depends. A good way to do it is put a `strict` doctype then run it through a validator.